# Распарсить строку на c#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Беру из файла StreamReader'ом строку вида xxxx:xxxxx@xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxx
Мне нужно распарсить строку на 4 части(до ":", до"@", после "@", и после второго ":") и присвоить значения 4 переменным. Вопрос, как будет выглядеть регулярное выражение для данной задачи?

Comment: А проблема-то в чем?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ответ `строка.Split(":@".ToCharArray());` елементы массива как-то уж присвоите в 4 переменные. Если очень скучно то регулярка будет выглядеть так `[:@]` :)

Comment: Сделал регулярку string pattern = @"(.*):(.*)@(.*):(.*)";

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал вот так

```
 public static void ParsingProxy()
    {
        var xx = new StreamReader("proxy.txt");
        string input = xx.ReadLine();
        string pattern = @"(.*):(.*)@(.*):(.*)";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        Match match = regex.Match(input);
        proxyLogin = match.Groups[1].Value;
        proxyPass = match.Groups[2].Value;
        proxy = match.Groups[3].Value;
        port = match.Groups[4].Value;
        //xx.Close();
    }
```